# VBA log in failing with getElementsByClassName

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to login to a website using VBA but I can't get it to click the submit button even though I do the things that I have found recommended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the HTML of the form:

```
<div class="pdForm login">
  <div class="pdLoginBox">
    <div class="pdLoginBoxInner">

    <div class="pdLoginFieldTitle">
        <div>Email Address</div>
        <div class="register"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="pdInput text" id="pdLogin-email">

    <br>
    <div class="pdLoginFieldTitle">
        <div>Password</div> 
        <div class="forgot"><a href="http://myaccount.asdf.com/retrievePassword.php" onclick="pdRetrievePasswordCopyEmail(this);"> Forgot your Password?</a></div>
    </div>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""  class="pdInput text" id="pdLogin-password">

    <div class="pdLoginBtn">
        <input type="image" src="http://myaccount.asdf.com/skins/standard_custom/butLogin.gif" border="0" vspace="4">
    </div>
        <div class="pdRegisterBtn">
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the VBA that I have tried and it fills in the name and password but will not submit even through it runs the code without error.

```
Sub Login()
    Dim lr As Long, a

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    my_url = "http://myaccount.asdf.com/login.php"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 1200
        .Width = 1200

        Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.READYSTATE = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

    ' Input the userid and password
    IE.Document.GetElementById("pdLogin-email").Value = "asdf@asdf.com"
    IE.Document.GetElementById("pdLogin-password").Value = "xxxxxx"

    Set ElementCol = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("pdLoginBtn")

    For Each btnInput In ElementCol
        btnInput.Click
    Next btnInput

End Sub
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pdLoginBtn").Children(0)
ElementCol.Click
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.That gives me a Run-time error : "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: The proposed line of code assumes that ElementCol  is declared as an element not as an element collection. Can you let me know the website address you are trying to login at?